# Upgrading React Native version from 0.65 to 0.67.4 caused an error: undefined is not a function on getScrollResponder()

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

[image]
Every time I click on this button in red circle like in the picture, I get this error
[image].

When I googled it, people say it could be related to react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll version issue but I don't have the package react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view or react-native-input-scroll-view installed. But I'm using ScrollView provided by react-native.

How do I fix this error.. help needed :(

Comment: If I were you, I'd try to track down the folder from which this keyboardawareHOC.js is being imported. 

Answer (score 1):

this solved my issue
i was using unstable native-base version

> "resolutions": {
> "native-base/@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "2.0.0"
> },